# Configure session time out tapestry

Tags: timeout, tapestry, pagecontext

my XML web is configured as follow [web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wloE.png), i don't even know why it is giving me that error,i would like to refresh my layout.tml  page after that 1 minute so i added to my layout this :  [meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Kwx.png) obviously tapestry doesn't know page Context.
Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: The web.xml screenshot shows an XML validation error but not the details. What message appears when you hover over the error?

Comment: The error occurred when i added the session-config:
The content of element type "web-app" must match "(icon?,display-name?,description?,distributable?,context-param*,filter*,filter-mapping*,listener*,servlet*,servlet-
 mapping*,session-config?,mime-mapping*,welcome-file-list?,error-page*,taglib*,resource-env-ref*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,login-config?,security-role*,env-
 entry*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*)".

Comment: the error was because of <!DOCTYPE web-app ......./> i removed it and replace <web-app> by : <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

Answer (score 0):

To get access to a session object in Tapestry, just @Inject request and call request.getSession()). Do this in the Java class, perhaps in a getMaxInactiveInterval() method. See See http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/state/displaysessioncontents for an example.